# Laravel database query – select inside foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've got a problem with a query in Laravel 5.3. I've got tables

`attendees->attendee_tag<-tags` (M:N relation)

and I would like to get attendees ordered by multiple tags, so I wrote this:

```
$query = Attendee::where('attendees.event_id', '=', $event_id);
$i = 1;
foreach($order_by as $column) {
    $tag = $this->tagService->findTagById($column['tag_id']);
    $sort_value = $tag->value_type == 'string' ? 'value_string_'.$i : 'value_int_'.$i;
    $query->join('attendee_tag as at_'.$i, function ($join) use ($tag, $i) {
        $join->on('attendees.id', '=', 'at_'.$i.'.attendee_id')
            ->where('at_'.$i.'.tag_id', '=', $tag->id);})
        ->select('at_'.$i.'.id as relationId_'.$i, 'at_'.$i.'.value_string as value_string_'.$i, 'at_'.$i.'.value_int as value_int_'.$i, 'attendees.id as id')
        ->orderBy($sort_value, $column['order']);
        $i++;
    }
$attendees = $query->get();
```

But I'm getting following sql error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'value_string_1' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `at_2`.`id` as `relationId_2`, `at_2`.`value_string` as `value_string_2`, `at_2`.`value_int` as `value_int_2`, `attendees`.`id` as `id` from `attendees` inner join `attendee_tag` as `at_1` on `attendees`.`id` = `at_1`.`attendee_id` and `at_1`.`tag_id` = 3 inner join `attendee_tag` as `at_2` on `attendees`.`id` = `at_2`.`attendee_id` and `at_2`.`tag_id` = 4 where `attendees`.`event_id` = 1 order by `value_string_1` asc, `value_string_2` asc limit 1000 offset 0)
```

It seems, that laravel has some optimalization and passes the select on `$join` function only once, in last iteration (second iteration in my opinion, I got 2 tags in request)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have `tags()` relation within Attendee model!

I tested it and it's working fine

```
$attendees = Attendee::join('attendee_tag', 'attendee_tag.attendee_id', '=', 'attendees.id')
                         ->join('tags', 'attendee_tag.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')->where('event_id', $event_id);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($order_by as $column) {
        $tag = $this->tagService->findTagById($column['tag_id']);
        $sort_value = $tag->value_type == 'string' ? 'value_string_' . $i : 'value_int_' . $i;
        $attendees->orderBy('tags.' . $sort_value, $column['order']);
        $i++;
    }
    $attendees->get();
```

PS: I don't know that `$order_by` is all about but I took the value of it from your code above, it should work just fine :) and I'm ready to tweak it for you if you want

Comment: this will sort tags, not attendees I think, am I right? I want to sort attendees by some tags

Comment: Please hold on I'm tweaking it :)

Comment: @user3216673 please check it again, I changed it and I tested it locally, hope it will work for you as well :)

Comment: nope, this will create a lot of separated objects, which has same attendee_id, because of joins ... attendees has a lot of tags, it is M:N relation between attendee and tag, so for each relation it creates row.